# How can i make my database method more future proof?

Tags: c#, database, refactoring, oledb

I am currently working on a new application with a database data transfer between two databases. I currently have a method written, but it looks like I can make this code way more compact. I read an article that used the `Using` Statement, but I'm not sure how I can implement this in my code. Furthermore, I would like to address that I have the following public declarations:

```
private IDbConnection ExportConnection = new OleDbConnection(Helper.CnnVal("ExportDatabase"));
    private IDbConnection SchoolConnection;
    private DataTable exportDb = new DataTable();
    private DataTable schoolDb = new DataTable();
    private OleDbCommandBuilder cb;
    private OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapterSchool;
    private OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapterExport;
    private OleDbCommand dbCommand;
    private string ZoekQuery { get; set; }
    private DataAccess db = new DataAccess();
    private string SchoolConnectionString;
    private string selectSchoolQuery;
```

This is the method:

```
public void InlezenClientGegevens()
{
    if ((bool)Checbox.IsChecked)
    {
        SchoolConnectionString = $@"I removed the string for privacy reasons";
        try
        {
            ExportConnection.Open();
            ZoekQuery = $"SELECT * FROM Client WHERE Cliëntnummer BETWEEN '{TxtVan.Text}' AND '{TxtTm.Text}'";
            dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(ZoekQuery, (OleDbConnection)ExportConnection);
            dataAdapterExport = new OleDbDataAdapter(ZoekQuery, (OleDbConnection)ExportConnection);
            dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            dataAdapterExport.AcceptChangesDuringFill = false;
            dataAdapterExport.Fill(exportDb);
            ExportConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        SchoolConnection = new OleDbConnection(SchoolConnectionString);
        try
        {
            SchoolConnection.Open();
            selectSchoolQuery = "SELECT * FROM Info";
            dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(selectSchoolQuery, (OleDbConnection)SchoolConnection);
            dataAdapterSchool = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectSchoolQuery, (OleDbConnection)SchoolConnection);
            dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            dataAdapterSchool.FillSchema(schoolDb, SchemaType.Source);
            dataAdapterSchool.Fill(schoolDb);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        try
        {
            cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapterSchool);
            cb.GetUpdateCommand();
            schoolDb.Merge(exportDb, false, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
            dataAdapterSchool.Update(schoolDb);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
public void InlezenClientGegevens()
{
    if ((bool)Checkbox.IsChecked)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(Helper.CnnVal("ExportDatabase")))
            {
                var ZoekQuery = $"SELECT * FROM client WHERE Cliëntnummer BETWEEN '{TxtVan.Text}' AND '{TxtTm.Text}'";
                using (var dbcommand = new OleDbCommand(ZoekQuery, connection))
                {
                    using (var exportAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(ZoekQuery, connection))
                    {
                        exportAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringFill = false;
                        exportAdapter.Fill(exportDb);
                    }
                }
            }
            using (var connection = new OleDbConnection($"))
            {
                var ZoekQuery = "SELECT * FROM info";
                using (var dbcommand = new OleDbCommand(ZoekQuery, connection))
                {

                    using (var SchoolAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(ZoekQuery, connection))
                    {
                        SchoolAdapter.FillSchema(schoolDb, SchemaType.Source);
                        SchoolAdapter.Fill(schoolDb);
                        using (var cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(SchoolAdapter))
                        {
                            cb.GetUpdateCommand();
                            schoolDb.Merge(exportDb, false, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
                            SchoolAdapter.Update(schoolDb);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }          
    }
}
```

Comment: *"code way more compact"* - [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Try not to keep the connection opened too long. Looks like you could move several variables into the `InlezenClientGegevens` method. I have had production apps go down because of designs like this.

Comment: I changed the code based on your feedback @TimSchmelter. I posted my changed code as an edit on this post, could you maybe check it out and see how i did? i tested the code and it worked

Comment: @Cleptus Thanks! i thought it was best practice to declare variables at the beginning of the class, i changed it now.

Comment: @JamesVH: for what you use the connection, Access?

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes, the export database is a static connection string, so I use a helper.cs and dataAccess.cs class to retrieve the connection string from app.config. For the other database, the connection string is based on user input, so I declare it in the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to open close the connection if you use `DataAdappter.Fill`. I would also use the `using` statement for everything implementing `IDisposable`(like for the `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand`, not necessary for the `DataTable`). So you should create the connection in the method.

You should also use parameters for your queries instead of string concatenation to avoid sql-injection. You should also try-parse the input first, to see if it's really an `int`:

```
public void InlezenClientGegevens()
{
    bool validVan = int.TryParse(TxtVan.Text, out int van);
    bool validTm = int.TryParse(TxtTm.Text, out int tm);
    if (!validVan || !validTm)
    {
        // inform user
        return;
    }

    if (Checkbox.IsChecked)
    {
        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(Helper.CnnVal("ExportDatabase")))
            {
                string zoekQuery = $"SELECT * FROM client WHERE Cliëntnummer BETWEEN ? AND ?";
                using (OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(zoekQuery, connection))
                {
                    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("Van", OleDbType.Integer).Value = van);
                    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("Tm", OleDbType.Integer).Value = tm);
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter exportAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(dbCommand))
                    {
                        exportAdapter.Fill(exportDb);
                    }
                }
            }
            // ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The code works exactly the same. However, I did not implement the valid if loop to check if it's really an integer, because the user can only insert integers in the text box. Is it still advised to write this if loop here?

Comment: @JamesVH: You should parse it to `int` anyway if thats the type of it in the database. Always pass the correct type via parameters, dont let the database guess the type. Thats inefficient and can cause other issues in the database. If you have to parse user-input always use `TryPase`. The implementation might change in future, dont expect it to be valid format

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your time and explanations! my code looks way cleaner now.

Comment: You should either **not** skip the validation in the method or make the method have parameters. If later the UI is changed and the "only integers" is removed your method would fail. For example, you could make it `InlezenClientGegevens(int van, int tm)`